# What alphabet is this?

Tags: croatia

I found this inscription on a Croatian island (island of [Cres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cres)), on a tombstone.

There were other inscriptions with this alphabet in that very cemetery.

I never saw this alphabet before though. What is it?

[image]

Comment: At quick glance it looks like [Glagolitsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glagolitic_script).

Comment: @seven-phases-max From the article: "That claim, however, has been resolutely[clarification needed] disproven." Ahh, Wikipedia. :)

Comment: @Spencer Sorry, I don't quite follow what you mean. What claim exactly?

Comment: @seven-phases-max The claim that St Jerome invented the Glagolitic script. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glagolitic_script#Hieronymian_version

Comment: @seven-phases-max Nothing really, just remarking on Wikipedia weirdness from the article you linked to. It seems that different W editors disagree on how thoroughly "debunked" the attribution of the script to St.Jerome is.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy It's definitely Glagolithic, but it's hard to identify the symbols cut off on the right side.  It transcribes into the Latin alphabet as **blizbudi?snd?**

Comment: @Spencer: I'm not surprised at all. When you don't include things like that, a pseudo-scientific or nationalist hothead invariably edits the page to add and elaborate on the thoroughly debunked theory. So might as well add the misconception and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: It definitely looks like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Croatian Glagolitic script:](http://www.croatianhistory.net/etf/et03.html).

> [image]

Which [has some variants over time, like this one:](http://www.ancientscripts.com/glagolitic.html)

> [image]

The text probably reads:
BLIZ BJDI GSP??I which means
bliže budi (GSP??I)
be closer to (‘the lord is hinted to in the comments but the last couple of letters before the I can not be decyphered because they are outside of the frame of the picture)

I initially translated GSP??I to hospita (lady) but ‘lord’ may well be intended.

Comment: Ok I added some more info. Just the Glagolitic letters are quite remarkable. Not all letters can be seen completely on the picture. The grave has a house shape so gospodi made me think of hospita.  But https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospić Maybe this city is meant?

Comment: "Bliže budi gospođi" Means 'will be closer to the Lord'.

Comment: @YellowSky: you beat me by a few minutes... [Господь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Господь)

Comment: Lady? Where did you get that? I'm not an expert in medieval Croatian, but "Blize budi gospodi" is pretty much understandable for most (all?) Slavic speakers and means "Be close(r), Lord" (no ladies, no wills, no tos). This is an appeal to the God (as in prayer, and I won't wonder if it's actually a quote from some common prayer).

Comment: he was a priest so his wife is out of question btw.

Comment: Lord is probably better than lady. If we could read the missing letters that would make it 100% clear.